# I have ROS dependencies in my virtual env everytime I create one with the python3 virtualenv command. Any idea why?

Tags: python, virtualenv, ros

So I recenetly installed ROS on my system after which I cannot create a python virtual environment without the ROS dependencies. This is my pip3 freeze's output. I have truncated the ouput to fit StackOverflow's standards.

```
dynamic-reconfigure==1.7.1
gazebo-plugins==2.9.2
gazebo-ros==2.9.2
gencpp==0.6.5
geneus==3.0.0
genlisp==0.4.18
genmsg==0.5.16
gennodejs==2.0.2
genpy==0.6.15
image-geometry==1.15.0
interactive-markers==1.12.0
joint-state-publisher==1.15.0
joint-state-publisher-gui==1.15.0
laser-geometry==1.6.7
message-filters==1.15.11
python-qt-binding==0.4.4
qt-dotgraph==0.4.2
qt-gui==0.4.2
qt-gui-cpp==0.4.2
qt-gui-py-common==0.4.2
resource-retriever==1.12.6
rosbag==1.15.11
rosboost-cfg==1.15.8
rosclean==1.15.8
roscreate==1.15.8
rosgraph==1.15.11
roslaunch==1.15.11
roslib==1.15.8
roslint==0.12.0
roslz4==1.15.11
rosmake==1.15.8
rosmaster==1.15.11
rosmsg==1.15.11
rosnode==1.15.11
rosparam==1.15.11
rospy==1.15.11
rosservice==1.15.11
rostest==1.15.11
rostopic==1.15.11
rosunit==1.15.8
roswtf==1.15.11
rqt-action==0.4.9
rqt-bag==0.5.1
rqt-bag-plugins==0.5.1
rqt-console==0.4.11
```

Answer (score 4):

You followed all of the ROS install instructions from the wiki. The last step is adding the command `source /opt/ros/{distro}/setup.bash` to your `.bashrc` file. This is the command that actually setups your `PYTHONPATH` and other needed variables.

If you don't want it to be automatically added you can simple remove that line from your bashrc. You'll just have to manually source the file from now on.